# ComboBox from a List or a Map Collection

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, httpsession

**EDIT:**

I want to show a `spring-mvc dropdown box` out of a object list which is a property from another class.

I did this after searching:

```
<sf:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/venta/save"
    method="post" commandName="venta">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Número de factura</td>
            <td><sf:input path="numero_factura" type="text" /></td>
            <td><sf:errors path="numero_factura" cssclass="error" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Producto:</td>
            <td><sf:select path="${producto.nombreProducto}">
                    <sf:option value="" label="...." />
                    <sf:options items="${productos}" />
                </sf:select></td>
            <td><sf:errors path="${producto.nombreProducto}"
                    cssclass="error" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Guardar cambios"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
    </table>
</sf:form>
```

The class I'm mapping is this:

> Venta.class

```
@Entity
public class Venta implements Serializable {

@Id
@NotNull
@Digits(integer=12, fraction = 0)
private Integer numero_factura;

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ManyToMany
@NotEmpty
private List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<Producto>();

private Date fechaDeIngreso;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Empleado empleado;

public Venta() {

}
...
```

}

And this is the controller:

```
@Controller
public class VentaController {

@Autowired
public IServiceProducto serviceProducto;

@Autowired
public IServiceVenta serviceVenta;

@Autowired
public IServiceEmpleado serviceEmpleado;

@RequestMapping("/venta")
public String showVenta(Model model, HttpSession session) {
    // Model es una interfaz que nos permite definir atributos en el modelo

    init(model);

    return "venta";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/venta/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleVenta(@Valid @ModelAttribute("venta") Venta ventaForm, BindingResult result, Model model,
        HttpSession session, RedirectAttributes ra) {

    try {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("productos", serviceProducto.getAll());
            return "venta";
        }

        Empleado empleado = (Empleado) session.getAttribute("empleado");
        empleado.setVenta(ventaForm);

        serviceVenta.exist(ventaForm);

        serviceEmpleado.addChild(empleado, ventaForm);

        ra.addFlashAttribute("resultado", "La venta fué agregada exitosamente");

        return "redirect:/venta";

    } catch (ServicioException e) {

        ra.addFlashAttribute("resultado", e.getMessage());
        return "redirect:/venta";
    }
}

public void init(Model model){
    Venta venta = new Venta();
    Producto producto = new Producto();
    model.addAttribute("venta", venta);
    model.addAttribute("producto", producto);
    model.addAttribute("productos", serviceProducto.getAll());
}
```

}

It gives me the view I was looking for, but this code is doing nothing when it comes to select an item from the dropdown box and hitting the *submit button*. It gives me no error and stay static in `http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/venta/save`

Please please help me, I'm almost there !

---

**OLD VERSION:**

I want to show a `combobox` in `jsp` from a list. It gives me a `dropdownlist` which I don't want.
I made a map with the list and it gives me the same result.

> Venta.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <sf:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/venta/save"
                <td>Producto</td>
                <td>
                    <sf:select path="productos">
                            <sf:option label="---select---" value="NONE"/>
                            <sf:options items="${productos}"/>
                    </sf:select>
                </td>
                <td><sf:errors path="productos" cssClass="error"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Guardar cambios"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </sf:form>
    <c:out value="${resultado}"></c:out>
</body>
</html>
```

> Necessary VentaController.java code to understand

```
@Controller
public class VentaController {

    @Autowired
    public IServiceProducto serviceProducto;

    @Autowired
    public IServiceVenta serviceVenta;

    @Autowired
    public IServiceEmpleado serviceEmpleado;
@RequestMapping("/venta")
public String showVenta(Model model, HttpSession session) {
    // Model es una interfaz que nos permite definir atributos en el modelo

    Venta venta = new Venta();
    model.addAttribute("venta", venta);
    List<Producto> listaProductos = serviceProducto.getAll();
    Map<String, String> mapaProductos = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    for (Producto producto : listaProductos) {
        mapaProductos.put(producto.getNombreProducto(), producto.getNombreProducto());
    }

    model.addAttribute("productos", mapaProductos);

    return "venta";
}
```

The result is a list with multiple selections. I'm aware that if I use the property multiple=false the multiple selection will be off but it still work in my case.

[DropdownList with multiple selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0z5H.png)

Still, I want a combobox function and not a dropdownlist without multiple selection.

This is my idea of what I want:

[select with options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XclTv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have this approach:

```
<sf:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/venta/save"
    method="post" commandName="ventaDTO">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Número de factura</td>
            <td><sf:input path="numero_factura" type="text" />
            <td><sf:errors path="numero_factura" cssclass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Producto:</td>
            <td><sf:select path="nombreProducto">
                    <sf:option value="" label="...." />
                    <sf:options items="${productos}" />
                </sf:select> <sf:errors path="nombreProducto" cssclass="error"
                    cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" /></td>
            <td>
            <td><sf:input path="cantidadProductos" type="text" />
                 <sf:errors
                    path="cantidadProductos" cssclass="error"
                    cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Guardar cambios"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</sf:form>
```

but still can't add another whole `table` in order to add a particular product in quantities. I was thinking about using `angularjs` but I'm new to that technology. I'll be very thankful for your help.